# Display a new link on the same page each time a new value is selected in dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web application in ASP.NET C# , following is my issue

I have a Drop down list, the requirement is each time I select an item in the drop down list, a new button should be displayed on the same page. This new button redirects to different window each time user select different options from the drop down menu. I am trying to use script something like below but it wont refresh each time a new value from the drop down list is selected

```
  <script runat="server">
     protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "BI_Config")
           {
             Button2.Style.Add("display", "inherit"); 
            }
        }
  </script>
```

The code for dropdown list is as below

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="BI_Config"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="GWI_Infostore"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Logging"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="RawDatafeeds"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="RawDataFeedsGWA"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Reporting"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Staging"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="View Reports" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

The code for button is as below

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"  Text="Display Model Report" OnClientClick="window.open('Model Report.xml');return false;" style="display: none;" />
```

I want a different button to display each time

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: how are you trying? can show us the code?

Comment: I have edited the problem for your better understanding

Comment: I understand you just want to open a different address depending on the selected value, why not just use u button and changing only its execution?

Comment: @PauloLima Can you please explain more clearly

Comment: I did added switch case for the different databases I select each time, it works fine for me now. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: I understand you want to open a different address to each selected certain value? Why do not you change the function to be performed at the time of selection of the value?